# What kind of training is required to be a civilian employee / resident on a starship?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

The Enterprise D in *TNG* has civilian employees on board, such as Mot the barber, Ms. Kyle the school teacher, and Guinan's wait staff in Ten Forward.  There are also families on board.

**What training are they required to complete in order to be permitted to live on a starship (apart from training required for their own careers)?**

Are they required to have training in basic ship functions and emergency procedures (in case of a ship disaster), or in basic combat training (in case the ship is boarded by hostiles)?  If so, is this training normally completed prior to becoming a resident on the ship, or is it typically completed on board?

Comment: i would hazard on board, as at this point their are people who live their whole lives on board ships, and only leaving them occasionally. born live die all on a space ship... what a life.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on what we see in the shows, the answer is probably very little. The Enterprise-D, unlike other ships is less of a military vessel and more of a mobile Starbase. Arriving non-military personnel are likely given a brief (verbal) tour of the ship's facilities, shown where the emergency shelters are and told what to do in the event of various catastrophes, as you would for someone who was going to work as a barmaid on a cruise liner (albeit with probably more emphasis on what to do if you lose air pressure or the gravity fails than on how to avoid drowning).

In the event of catastrophic failure of life support, as for instance happens in TNG : Night Terrors and TNG : Disaster, we see the Enterprise itself (via lighting, visual and audio cues) and enlisted crew directing civilians to designated shelter areas such as Ten Forward, automated lifeboats and automated transporters. The need for a non-officer to do anything proactive in an emergency, aside from following orders, appears to be essentially nil.

With regard to *when* these emergency procedures are laid out, probably the closest we get is in the TNG episode "[A Matter of Honor](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/134.htm)". New personnel are immediately shown to an '*indoctrination session*'. I would assume that this includes a presentation about what to do in the event of a red-alert, what to do if your dreams manifest themselves, what to do if you find yourself pregnant by a ball of glowing light, etc.

> **RIKER:** *Welcome aboard the Enterprise. I'm Commander William Riker, your First Officer. Those of you who are here as replacements
>   will step outside follow Lieutenant Lewis. He will assign you to your
>   crew quarters.* (to the Benzite) *Ensign, you're here on the exchange
>   programme. If you'll just follow Mister Crusher.*
>
> ...
>
> **RIKER:** *It's nice to have you here, Ensign. There will be a briefing and indoctrination session in fifteen minutes.*

Comment: +1 for "albeit with probably more emphasis on what to do if you lose air pressure or the gravity fails than on how to avoid drowning"

Comment: +1 for "what to do if your dreams manifest themselves, what to do if you find yourself pregnant by a ball of glowing light, etc."

Comment: @Nerrolken - All very real possibilities.

Comment: @N.Soong - Data does function as a flotation device if you land in the water.

Comment: @Richard good to know in case Data's emotion chip is off and he tries to play a practical joke (cough cough First Contact) ;)

Comment: One thing I always found very strange was the general lack of access control. Anyone could basically go anywhere. Civilians even showing up on the bridge during heated negotiations with the Romulans. It seems like they would have been vetted much more than a barmaid on a cruise line and with that probably some space training.